# Abrir windows explorer usando o PHP e/ou JS

Tags: php, javascript

Bom dia a todos.

É possível abrir o Windows Explorer, na estação do cliente em uma determinada pasta de rede (compartilhamento windows) seja com o próprio PHP e/ou JS.

Já tentei com o exec() do php e com o window.open(fiel:///) do JS , mas sem sucesso.

A aplicação está rodando em linux na mesma rede das estações clientes.

Comment: Acredito que isso dependa muito mais das permissões de segurança do navegador do que da linguagem.

Comment: Os meus teste foram feitos tanto no firefox quanto no chrome, que são os mais utilizados aqui pelos meus usuários.

Comment: Em geral o explore permite isso

Answer (score 3):

> É possível abrir o Windows Explorer utilizando PHP?

Não! PHP é uma linguagem que roda em server-side; Num contexto geral voce não vai conseguir interagir com recursos nativos no client-side, ou seja, no navegador do usuário;

> É possível abrir o Windows Explorer utilizando Javascript?

Utilizando o Internet Explorer (provavelmente isso não é possível com outros browsers), você consegue utilizar alguns recursos do ActiveX, porem só testei fazer isso com HTML salvo na própria máquina; Usando algo como:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.open("nomeDoArquivo.html", "NomeDaNovaJanela");
</script>
```

Não conheço o contexto ao qual você precisa utilizar esta solução, mas do ponto de vista de segurança isso não é nada aconselhável; Além do fato de a maioria dos browsers não permitirem ações como essa, você irá enfrentar diversas restrições com software de anti-virus que consideram ações como essa uma ameaça;

Recomendo pensar numa outra abordagem para resolver o seu problema; Manipular diretórios no cliente não me parece ser uma abordagem para soluções Web-based, pelo simples fato de que você não tem como garantir que determinado diretório exista no cliente;

Answer (score 1):

Da pra fazer por JavaScript e ActiveX.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function abrirPrograma()
        {
            var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            var fileLeft = "\"D:\\Caminho\\para\\o\\arquivo\"";
            var fileRight= "\"D:\\Caminho\\para\\o\\arquivo2\"";
            shell.Run(fileLeft + " " + fileRight);
        }
        </script>
```

Para abrir usa um link/botão/etc... especificando a função:

```
<a href="abrirPrograma()">Abrir Programa</a>
```

Comment: Pelo que li está solução so vai funcionar no IE, que não seria o caso.
O ActiveXObject só é suportado pelo IE.
Nos outros navegadores da o erro "ActiveXObject is not defined".

Comment: Sim, mas eu só conheço soluções que envolva o IE. para o Firefox será com o href file:\\\\\ e no chrome \\ mas funciona mal.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas procuro algo crossbrowser, até mesmo o file:\\\ não está funcionando pois pelo que li tanto o Firefox quanto o Chrome estão bloqueando.